# Unity 2D, character will not move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

So i have followed this guide https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/live-session-2d-platformer-character-controller#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b695

And i've basically followed everything step by step.

Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PhysicsObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float minGroundNormalY = .65f;
    public float gravityModifier = 1f;
    protected Vector2 targetVelocity;
    protected bool grounded;
    protected Vector2 groundNormal;

    protected Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    protected Vector2 velocity;
    protected ContactFilter2D contactFilter;
    protected RaycastHit2D[] hitBuffer = new RaycastHit2D[16];
    protected List<RaycastHit2D> hitBufferList = new List<RaycastHit2D>(16);

    protected const float minMoveDistance = 0.001f;
    protected const float shellRadius = 0.01f;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        contactFilter.useTriggers = false;
        contactFilter.SetLayerMask(Physics2D.GetLayerCollisionMask (gameObject.layer));
        contactFilter.useLayerMask = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        targetVelocity = Vector2.zero;
        ComputeVelocity();
    }

    protected virtual void ComputeVelocity()
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        velocity += gravityModifier * Physics2D.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.x = targetVelocity.x;

        grounded = false;

        Vector2 deltaPosition = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector2 moveAlongGround = new Vector2(groundNormal.y, -groundNormal.x);
        Vector2 move = moveAlongGround * deltaPosition.x;
        Movement(move, false);

        move = Vector2.up * deltaPosition.y;
        Movement(move, true);
    }

    void Movement(Vector2 move, bool yMovement)
    {
        float distance = move.magnitude;
        if (distance > minMoveDistance)
        {
           int count =  rb2d.Cast(move, contactFilter, hitBuffer, distance + shellRadius);
            hitBufferList.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                hitBufferList.Add(hitBuffer[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < hitBufferList.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 currentNormal = hitBufferList[i].normal;
                if (currentNormal.y < minGroundNormalY)
                {
                    grounded = true;
                    if (yMovement)
                    {
                        groundNormal = currentNormal;
                        currentNormal.x = 0;
                    }
                }
                float projection = Vector2.Dot(velocity, currentNormal);

                if (projection < 0)
                {
                    velocity = velocity - projection * currentNormal;
                }
                float modifiedDistance = hitBufferList[i].distance - shellRadius;
                distance = modifiedDistance < distance ? modifiedDistance : distance;
            }
        }
        rb2d.position = rb2d.position + move.normalized * distance;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPlatformerController : PhysicsObject
{
    public float jumpTakeOffSpeed = 7;
    public float maxSpeed = 7;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    protected override void ComputeVelocity()
    {
        Vector2 move = Vector2.zero;
        move.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
        {
            velocity.y = jumpTakeOffSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
        {
            if (velocity.y > 0)
            {
                velocity.y = velocity.y * 0.5f;
            }
        }
        targetVelocity = move * maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

If you check that link it will probably have some animations added to it, i have not gotten that far yet.

So atm my char just stands completly still and does not move. Below is the picture.

Comment: First time posting btw, so it was kinda weird with adding the code. But basically its 2 separate scripts. 

1 that is for the physics, then 2nd script for the player controls.
So the first code ends and 2nd begins when it reaches the "using system.collections" So its not all in 1 script. 

Used to a bit simpler way where it was just to add [code] >code< [code/]

Edit: Also it did not add the link to the picture, but if you want to know anything specific about the Inspector, just ask. The RigidBody is using Kinematic, tried to change to dynamic, but same thing.

Comment: Just entered an empty comment `<!-- -->` between the 2 scripts. Code must be indented by at least 4 spaces. Nothing to do with your problem, but can merge the very last nested if: `else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && velocity.y > 0)
            {
                velocity.y = velocity.y * 0.5f;
            }`. because of C#'s short-circuit evaluation, `velocity.y > 0` is only evaluated when `Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When inheriting from Unity objects (MonoBehaviours in general), if you create a new Unity lifecycle function (Start, Awake, Update, etc), it will ignore the inheriting class' implementation.

In this case, `PlayerPlatformerController` is implementing an empty `Start`, which means `Start` won't be called on `PhysicsObject`.

This means this code **will not run**:

```
contactFilter.useTriggers = false;
contactFilter.SetLayerMask(Physics2D.GetLayerCollisionMask (gameObject.layer));
contactFilter.useLayerMask = true;
```

Which could be a game breaking issue since you are modifying physics related arguments there.